# Add locale moment to an AngularJS app

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, momentjs

I'm trying to configure the locale language for an AngularJS app based on Yeoman.

When I serve the dist package after building my app (grunt build), the script reference dissapears.
Here's a list of my dependencies on the index.html file.

```
<!-- build:js(.) scripts/vendor.js -->
<!-- bower:js -->
<script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-touch/angular-touch.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/moment/moment.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-moment/angular-moment.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/ngstorage/ngStorage.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-ui-select/dist/select.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-loading-bar/build/loading-bar.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-hotkeys/build/hotkeys.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/moment/locale/es.js"></script>
<!-- endbower -->
<!-- endbuild -->
```

Where should I place this script reference to keep it for the dist package?

```
<script src="bower_components/moment/locale/es.js"></script>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I just had a Déjà vu with this question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should insert it **outside** the `bower` section, like this:

```
<!-- build:js(.) scripts/vendor.js -->
<!-- bower:js -->
<script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
…
<script src="bower_components/angular-loading-bar/build/loading-bar.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-hotkeys/build/hotkeys.min.js"></script>
<!-- endbower -->
<script src="bower_components/moment/locale/es.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->
```

Your grunt/gulp task is automatically filling the `bower:js` section (each time there a change to `bower.json` happens) by looking into `main` entry in `bower.json` files of every bower component you require. The locale files are not listed as main files, so even if you'd put it between `bower:js` and `endbower` section manually, it'd dissapear with the nearest change of the `bower.json` file, or during the build process.

The code you put outside the `bower` section will stay there.

And in the end, during the build process, all the files linked **between `build:js` and `endbuild`** comments are concatenated into one `vendor.js` file.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks for the explanation about how bower works with these sections.

Comment: Glad to be of help. To be precise it's not exactly bower itself but a grunt plugin within run within a `watch` or `build` task.

Comment: Not working for me :    <!-- build:js(.) scripts/vendor.js -->
    <!-- bower:js -->
    <script src="bower_components/moment/moment.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-moment/angular-moment.js"></script>
    <!-- endbower -->
    <!-- endbuild -->
        <!-- build:js({.tmp,app}) scripts/scripts.js -->
        <script src="scripts/lib/utils.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/controllers/main.js"></script>
        <script src="bower_components/moment/locale/fr.js"></script>
        <!-- endbuild -->